# Reference cell with a name range in VLOOKUP

Tags: arrays, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to do a VLOOKUP, but for the table array, I'm trying to reference a single cell that holds the name range value. Is there a way to make the VLOOKUP recognise the name range without using INDIRECT?

The addon I'm using to convert the Excel doc to a HTML interface, doesn't allow for INDIRECT unfortunately. VBA won't work as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the range (e.g. *MyRange*) is in A1 then something like this,

```
with activesheet
    application.vlookup(123, range(.Range("A1").value), 2, false)
    application.vlookup(123, range(.Cells(1, 1).value), 2, false)
end with
```

Note that it is important that the parent worksheet of the cell containing the name of the named range be specified. Not so much for the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) actually getting the range with the string returned.